# Unhandled DirectoryNotFound exception thrown using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles and "subst" command

Tags: c#, exception, foreach

### Background:

I'm trying to write a little program that recursively goes through all files contained in a user specified folder (and all its subfolders). The program is supposed to check the size of each file and if it matches a user defined value,  copy their full path (File.FullName) to a text box control I've setup on the only form of the program.
The trouble is that because of the intended use of the program (working with recovered files and folders from damaged partitions on external drives), often the path length goes well over the maximum path length limit. In order to marginally circumvent this I decided to map the user selected starting directory to a virtual drive using the Win32 command line function "subst".

### Incriminated Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtboxSizeFilter.Text != "")//code will execute only if a size filter has been provided by the user
        {

            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    List<char> driveLetters = new List<char>(26); // Allocate space for alphabet
                    for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) // increment from ASCII values for A-Z
                    {
                        driveLetters.Add(Convert.ToChar(i)); // Add uppercase letters to possible drive letters
                    }

                    foreach (string drive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
                    {
                        driveLetters.Remove(drive[0]); // removed used drive letters from possible drive letters
                    }

                    GlobalVars.Drive = driveLetters[0].ToString() + ":"; //gets the next available drive letter to be used as the virtual drive and adds a convenient ":" at the end

                    string command = "subst " + GlobalVars.Drive + " " + "\"" + folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\""; //command to be passed to "cmd". Ex. Content= subst J: "C:\users\someuser\somelongnamefolder\some longer name folder with spaces" 
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c " + command);//launches the command prompt and initiates subst. This section has been tested and works fine.

                    DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(GlobalVars.Drive);//here i start at the drive letter that points to the desired directory.
                   foreach (var fi in DI.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))//searches for any file in all dirs. THE EXCEPTION "DirectoryNotFound" OBJECT OF THIS QUESTION IS THROWN EXACTLY HERE.
                   {
                        try //I need this because I might throw a PathTooLongException despite my use of subst
                        {
                            if (fi.Length == Convert.ToInt64(txtboxSizeFilter.Text))//if the size of the file is = to target size then I add the full path name to the textbox along with its actual size (for debug purposes only).
                            {
                                txtboxResults2Confirm.Text = txtboxResults2Confirm.Text + fi.FullName.ToString() + "_" + fi.Length.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                            }
                         }
                         catch (PathTooLongException)//if the path is too long, indicate it with the codeword "SKIP"
                         {
                            txtboxResults2Confirm.Text = txtboxResults2Confirm.Text + "SKIP" + Environment.NewLine;
                         }

                    }   
                    btnConfirm.Enabled = true;//enables the other button on the form that will actually delete the files.
                }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("INPUT SIZE FIRST!");
        }
    }
```

### Problem/Research/Question:

As specified in the comments and the tile, an unhandled DirectoryNotFound exception occurs at the second foreach statement (as indicated by the IDE, Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013). Doing a step by step debug indicates that the foreach loop actually works for a while and then "randomly" throws the exception. I was able to verify that it goes through all the files in the root directory and at least a large part of the first subdirectory without any trouble at all (because of the large amount of files/subdirectories I wasn't able to pinpoint where exactly the failure occurs). The error states that the directory not found is the root one (so, to follow the example in the comments: "Unable to find J:\"). I've tried to follow the first catch with another to handle the DirectoryNotFound exception to not avail, which makes sense since the exception seems to originate directly in the foreach statement. I've also tried to wrap the entire foreach statement into a try-catch framework without any luck. Finally, getting rid of the whole "subst" section and just working with the user selected path produces no such error.
My question is, why is the exception thrown? And why am I not able to handle it in any way? Is there an alternate approach to this problem that would ensure the avoidance of the DirectoryNotFound exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Process.Start` does exactly that: it starts a new process (with its own main thread, etc etc) which may or may not complete by the time your next line of code in the original program executes. A couple of ways to resolve this: a) call `DefineDosDevice` which will mean the "subst" command runs in the current program thread, or b) grab the pipe to the cmd process and listen on it for completion. Both are of intermediate difficulty, pick your poison.

Of course, the exception that you're experiencing is because the `subst` command didn't complete in time when the code to enumerate the (yet un-aliased) directory executes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the process would not be completed before the next line (keep making the same mistake) and DefineDosDevice did the trick! Thank you for providing me with the solution but must of all for giving me the answer I scratched my head over for the better part of the day!